# standard result on expanding a symmetric operator

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

These [notes](https://stt.msu.edu/Academics/ClassPages/uploads/SS20/953-1/Ustat.pdf) state that a result from the Hilbert-Schmidt theory of integral
equations is: For given i.i.d. random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, any symmetric, square integrable function $A(x_1, x_2)$ admits a series
expansion of the form,
$$
A(x_1, x_2) = 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k\phi_k(x_1)\phi_k(x_2).
$$
The notes say this equality is interpreted as $L_2$ convergence of the infinite sum, and that there is a comparable result for almost sure convergence under additional assumptions on $A$.

I am not familiar with "the Hilbert-Schmidt theory of integral equations". Is this the result the same as this [Hilbert-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem)? Because on the surface the theorem seems weaker since it is about expanding linear operators whereas the notes talk about expanding an arbitrary symmetric function. Also where is the result for a.s. convergence from?

Comment: See [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem).